# Are there some elegant ways to partially save a huge form on Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

This is more of a conceptual question rather than specifically a technical one.

I have a Model that has like 20-30 entries on the database, there are 5-6 required fields and currently I'm driving my Form class from ModelForm.

We have designed a somewhat elegant UI at Front-End in our template that takes these fields step by step so we don't overwhelm the user with a giant fieldset on a single response.

Now the problem is our Required Model fields are scattered through these steps (Single-Page Accordion UI) and we are trying to save the actual data on a step by step basis so the end user will be able to continue filling the form from the last checkpoint later on.

How do we approach this situation, considering the Model also has a UUID that will be Not Editable, So I'm assuming I can't just use some temporary tables in between the process, or can I?

Comment: You can save all the forms in the front-end state, and on submit send this as a whole to the backend.

Comment: @Sumithran Thanks for the quick response. However the user might fill let's say 3 steps and leave the page and come back tomorrow to continue the next 4 steps to say! So I think I'm gonna need to find a way in back-end so I can retrieve the partially filled form later.

Comment: yeah, in that case, you can send the form data after every time the user changes the data like google docs do, it waits for some time let's say 5 seconds after the user changes any inputs, then after 5 seconds you can auto-save the whole data to backend, so the filled data will be saved.

Comment: Guess I found some sort of concepts around the same situation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168432/django-save-incomplete-progress-on-form?rq=2
Will try it out and see what happens...